# Cambiar color de fondo de un input segun un stream de datos

Tags: css, angular, websocket, rxjs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Angular y tengo un template que cuenta con una serie de **inputs**.

Dichos campos reciben mediante un **@Input()** valores desde una conexión con un broker de mensajería y los muestra en tiempo real al usuario.

Hasta aquí todo bien, el comportamiento que he de implementar implica cambiar el color de fondo de dichos inputs (de manera individual) mediante ciertas clases CSS en función de dos factores:

- El `<input>` ha de ponerse verde cuando comience a recibir valores del stream de datos
- Ha de ponerse naranja cuando pasen 10 segundos sin haber recibido ningún dato

Había pensado en utilizar la directiva `[ngClass]` de Angular para asignar dichas clases según el valor recibido por otro observable con el nombre de la clase a aplicar, asignado según uno de los 2 casos anteriores), algo así:

```
 export class Component implements OnInit {
 @Input() valor:number;
```

---

```
<input [className]="'status'"
 type="text" [value]="valor" readOnly="true">
```

Las clases CSS ya están creadas pero requeriría ayuda en la parte de emitir el nombre de dicha clase en la suscripción al stream de datos. Adjunto a continuación una captura del **servicio** que se suscribe al flujo de datos y emite los valores para que se pueda ver más claro:

```
private valoresSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
public valores$ = this.valoresSource.asObservable();
```

---

```
this.client.onConnect = () => {
  this.client.subscribe("/topic/nombreTopic" + param, e => {
      //some checks
      //Aquí se deberían hacer las comprobaciones para enviar un nombre de clase CSS u otro
      this.valoresSource.next(e.body);
    };
  });
}
```

PD: Si fuera de utilidad para simplificar la solución cabe la posibilidad de añadir un campo a cada mensaje recibido por el stream con la hora actual (en ms).

**Simulación en stackblitz:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dkdzcp

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer un ejemplo en stackblitz de lo que tienes?

Comment: @Legna no he usado nunca stackblitz pero he creado una simulación del proyecto muy básica, espero que te sirva (adjunto el enlace a la pregunta original). La idea como decía era que cuando se empiecen a recibir valores se ponga la casilla color verde y cuando pasen 10 segundos se vayan poniendo color naranja hasta que vuelvan a recibir datos y se volverán verde de nuevo (los colores se activan de manera individual por casilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `setInterval` para lograr lo que deseas.

```
iniciarSuscripcion() {
    this.intervalo = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.contador >= this.tiempoDeComprobacionesEnSegundos) {
        this.activo = false;

        this.logDeTiempos.push({
          tiempo: this.contador,
          tipo: "MAS DE 10 SEGUNDOS"
        });
      }
      this.contador++;
    }, 1000);

    this.streamService.iniciarSuscripcion();
  }
```

Solo agrega estas lineas mas al `subscribe`:

```
this.streamService.valores$.subscribe(valores => {
      this.valores = valores;

      this.logDeTiempos.push({
        tiempo: this.contador,
        tipo: "STREAM RECIBIDO"
      });


      this.contador = 0;
      this.activo = true;
    });
```

Y no olvides destruir el `interval` que creamos al salir del componente, de otra manera se seguira ejecutando:

```
 ngDestroy(){
    clearInterval(this.intervalo)
  }
```

Y para pasar el estilo deseado solo ocupas hacer esto al componente en tu html:

```
<app-child 
    [valor]="valores[i]" 
    [status]="activo?'active':'standby'">
</app-child>
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msefbu)

Answer (score 3):

La solución más fácil e inmediata sería usar `setTimeout` con `clearTimeout`.

Una vez se recibe un nuevo dato del `Subject<>`, se pone el estado "activo" (color verde) y empieza a correr un `setTimeout` de diez segundos. Cuando este *timeout* se completa, el estado pasa a "inactivo".
La gracia está en mantener ese *timeout* en una variable para poderlo cancelar. El *timeout* se cancela justo cuando se recibe un nuevo evento del `Subject<>` y se pone a correr un nuevo *timeout*.

```
type BrokerState = 'active' | 'inactive';

@Component({...})
export class Parent implements OnInit {
  state: BrokerState = 'inactive';
  timeout: NodeJS.Timer;

  // ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.source.subscribe(value => {
      // ...

      // Cancelamos el timeout actual.
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);

      // Cambia el state
      this.state = 'active';

      // Reasignamos el nuevo timeout de 10s
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.state = 'inactive';
      }, 10000); // 10s
    });
  }
}
```

Espero que sirva.